# App to show reports with Python, Pandas, Matplotlib engine

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jinja2

I want to create a very simple App which shows me in a browser, reports of the month I select which are created by Pandas and Matplotlib.

I would like to include a filter in the Browser to select what report should I show and then, if possible, include an option to download the corresponding PDF.

Which are the best Tools to achive this goal? Is there a little example that you know of something similar?

I have seen the library jinja2 and pfgkit to create pdf and html reports, but I dont know how to match this with the filter I wish to add the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Dash library to build simple web apps that display reports obtained with Pandas and Matplotlib. Maybe you could take a look at that library and see if it is useful for you:

https://plot.ly/products/dash/

Hope the link is useful; regards!

Comment: Thanks so much! And do you know what is the difference with Reportlab? Have you used reportlab?

Comment: @Laura Reportlab is for creating PDF documents with python

Comment: Do you know if with Dash + Plotly you can produce reports? I mean, writting reports + plots and download them as a PDF (Not download plots as PDF, instead the plots + something that I write )

Comment: yes, Dash is a library for deploying your reports inside a web app. A nice thing about this library is that it works for python & pandas, so you write your report with pandas, produce the dataframe, and display it as a table on your web app, from this, you can also generate the corresponding PDF downloadable. There is such a report in the following example: https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-vanguard-report/